# LWJGL—How to Animate Sprites from a Sprite Sheet Using Certain Keys?

Tags: java, 2d, lwjgl, rpg

I'm talking here about walking animations and such for a 16-bit RPG. I have a simple sprite sheet that contains walking animations for all directions (up, left, down, and right), but I'm having trouble getting LWJGL to animate them—how would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is posted [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/147715/lwjgl-how-to-animate-and-render-characters-using-a-sprite-sheet). Knowledge regarding [shaders in LWJGL](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjPqOvo36fWAhVLlFQKHSSsBgwQtwIIPzAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dq_dS3JuoeDw&usg=AFQjCNHMY8t2wtWBwdNaDxGnaf1tFslXeg) is required.