# LWJGL—How to Animate and Render Characters Using a Sprite Sheet

Tags: java, animation, sprites, lwjgl, rpg

I'm making an RPG similar to Super Nintendo RPGs in the early '90s. I'm handling movement much like Squaresoft's *Final Fantasy IV*. [image: FFIV Gameplay]

Notice that the player never actually **changes his x and y positions on screen**. What I'm asking, to be precise, is how could I, in LWJGL through user input (say, the arrow keys), take the **sprite sheet I have of my character's movement animations** and render them in a [partially] fluid animation like above?

I've been perusing the internet for hours, and I've not found a surefire way to do this. I don't have any code as of yet; I'm more or less looking for a guideline or some pointers in the right direction concerning how I might tackle this.

And, to note, this'll be a rather large game, so I want to focus partially on speed and efficiency—that meaning that I don't want to dive into Slick2D and libGDX unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Here's a great tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWEDJ6fFJyk

Don't worry about researching for the best possible solution, start prototyping asap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much easier than you think. In your shader you need to have a uniform containing the size of one sprite and the position of the current sprite (in a normalized coordinate system, where `(0; 0)` is the upper left corner and `(1; 1)` is the lower right corner). Then you simply need to multiply the texture coordinates with the size of one sprite and add the position of the sprite to it:

```
in vec2 a_textureCoords;

uniform sampler2D u_sampler;
uniform vec2 u_spriteSize;
uniform vec2 u_spritePosition;

out vec4 color;

void main(void) {
    color = texture(u_sampler, a_textureCoords * u_spriteSize + u_spritePosition;
}
```

Loading in the uniforms is also very easy. If you have a variable `delay` storing the amount of milliseconds between the two sprites, then you can do

```
if (!playerMoving) {
    // Load in the position of the standing sprite
} else {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() % (2 * delay) < delay) {
        // Load in the position of the first walking sprite
    } else {
        // Load in the position of the second walking sprite
    }
}
```

if you have more than 2 walking sprites, then you should store the sprite position in an array and load them dynamically:

```
private Vector2[] positions = new Vector2[] {
    new Vector2(0.5, 0),
    new Vector2(0, 0.5),
    new Vector2(0.5, 0.5)
};

    if (!playerMoving) {
    // Load in the position of the standing sprite
} else {
    int currentPos = System.currentTimeMillis() % (positions.length * delay) / positions.length;
    Vector2 pos = positions[currentPos];
    // Load in pos
}
```